# Ember.JS creating record with hasMany array

Tags: ember.js

I am attempting to create a computed property that returns an array of objects, each of which in turn has a property containing another array of objects. The computed property works, and I can set the properties which have primitive types while calling createRecord(), but populating a property of hasMany eludes me.

I have made a JSBin: http://jsbin.com/oyAlOhA/1/edit?html,js,output

Basically what I would like to do is be able to copy the behavior from the left (green) panel into the right (grey) panel, but by creating records instead of storing them with a fixture adapter.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
newUpper.set('gammas', testing);
```

to this:

```
newUpper.get('gammas').pushObjects(testing.map(function(id) { return App.Gamma.find(id); }));
```

First of all, the gammas property is a `DS.ManyArray` instance, not a regular array. So you shouldn't set it directly. Secondly, it's expecting `App.Gamma` instances, not IDs.